# How to convert it SCSS inline styles in your HTML

Tags: html, sass

I have been working with quite a lot with Grafana. I have asked through support and different forums and unfortunate Grafana does not support external SCSS and that the only way to be able to use SCSS is to combine it with HTML. Meaning that I need to convert it into inline styles in my HTML which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="grid">

    <div class="product">
      <div class="product-image">
        <a href="https://www.jdsports.se/product/nike-air-force-1-shadow-womens/393242_jdsportsse/" target="_blank">
          <img style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/9pdOpoF.png);" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-description">
        <h1>
          Nike Air Force 1 Shadow Womens sfg sdfg sdf gdfs sdf
        </h1>
        <div class="brand-wrapper">
          <span class="brand">(Jdsports)</span>
          <span class="id">ID 2200</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the code I have used for SCSS which works when it is external however since Grafana does not support it, I need to convert it....

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap");

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .product {
    width: 99%;
    max-width: 333px;

    .product-image {
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 225px;
      

      a {
        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center;
        }
      }
    }

    .product-description {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 20px;
      max-width: 100%;
      align-items: center;

      h1 {
        display: -webkit-box;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .brand-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .brand {
          margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        }
      }
    }

    margin-right: 1%;
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I convert it into inline styles in my HTML?

Comment: This is SCSS, not CSS

Comment: @ΛRYΛN Oh thanks! I have now edited it :) Thank you. Was abit too fast when typing it

Comment: By internal SCSS, do you mean convert it into inline styles in your HTML (with `style=""`), or to convert it into CSS in `<style></style>` tags?

Comment: @ΛRYΛN I do not believe that `<style>...</style>` would work through Grafana. In that case it means inline styles as `style=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your converted HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body style='background:#222; color:#fff; font-family:"Roboto", serif'>

  <div class="grid" style="display:flex; margin:0 auto; max-width:1200px">

    <div class="product" style="margin-right:0; max-width:333px; width:99%" width="99%">
      <div class="product-image" style="height:100%; max-height:225px; max-width:100%" height="100%">
        <a href="https://www.jdsports.se/product/nike-air-force-1-shadow-womens/393242_jdsportsse/" target="_blank">
          <img style="background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:100%; width:100%; background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/9pdOpoF.png)" height="100%" width="100%">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-description" style="align-items:center; display:block; margin-top:20px; max-width:100%">
        <h1 style="-webkit-box-orient:vertical; -webkit-line-clamp:2; display:-webkit-box; font-size:1rem; height:40px; margin-bottom:10px; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; text-transform:uppercase" height="40" align="center">
          Nike Air Force 1 Shadow Womens sfg sdfg sdf gdfs sdf
        </h1>
        <div class="brand-wrapper" style="-webkit-box-pack:center; -webkit-justify-content:center; align-items:center; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center">
          <span class="brand" style="margin-bottom:0.5rem">(Jdsports)</span>
          <span class="id">ID 2200</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

How I converted it:

1. Convert SCSS into CSS with [jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css).
2. Place CSS in `<head><style></style></head>` tags in your HTML.
3. Run HTML in [Premailer HTML styles inliner](https://premailer.io).

Comment: Woah! Was exactly what I was looking for! :D I did not know it was that easy as you described it on how to convert it. I do appreciate it alot!